# How can you change the non-visual editor's background color?

Tags: html-editor

I am using Wordpress with theme 2011 and the "Jetpack Markdown" extension. 
When you are using the "Jetpack Markdown" extension, you cannot use the visual editor, so I am using the non-visual pure text editor. 
Also, I cannot stand pure white backgrounds, as I'm getting headaches from a pure white background.

So I need to change the background color of the non-visual pure text editor and its fullscreen companion.

I have tried adding this

```
function my_theme_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_theme_add_editor_styles' );
```

to my `functions.php` and using an `editor-style.css` with this content:

```
body { padding: 0; background: #ddf; }
```

But pitifully, this does only change the background color of the *visual* editor. 
How could I change the background color of the *non-visual* editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the `#content` selector, but within the scope of the page (the editor style loads inside the Tiny MCE iframe, which is why it won't affect the non-visual editor).

You can either print the styles in the admin head, or use an external stylesheet:

```
function wpse_142641_text_editor_styles( $hook_suffix ) {
    if ( $hook_suffix === 'post.php' || $hook_suffix === 'post-new.php' ) {
        // Either enqueue external stylesheet
        // wp_enqueue_style( 'my-editor', get_template_directory_uri() . '/text-editor.css' );

        // OR print out to <head />
        echo '<style>
    #content {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>';
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_142641_text_editor_styles' );
```

Comment: I just tested your version and it works but only half. It does not change the background color for the fullscreen pure text editor.